# is Spring WS is JAX-WS compliant

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

**Is Spring WS is compliant with JAX-WS?** To be more elaborate,

- Does Spring-WS provides features according to JAX-WS standards?
- Does Spring-WS covers all the features specified in JAX-WS?

**Background with respect to question:** 
We are trying to develop multiple web services. We want to come up with standard-framework for web service before starting those projects. So we want to stick to one WS implementation, either Spring WS or JAX-WS. Based on research I found out many details about both implementation (mentioned below). Even though it is not officially mentioned in Spring WS project that it follows JAX-WS, I want to know whether it is still complaint with JAX-WS standards.

**Few of the known Facts:**

"Spring supports only contract first WSDL to code"  VS "JAX-WS provides both Code-WSDL, WSDL-Code"

"In Spring WS, Incoming request handled at  XML messages request level (flexibility)" VS "Incoming request handled as method calls."

**Spring WS standards ([link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d4e96))**

- SOAP 1.1 and 1.2
- WSDL 1.1 and 2.0 (XSD-based generation only supported for WSDL 1.1)
- WS-I Basic Profile 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and 2.0
- WS-Addressing 1.0 and the August 2004 draft
- SOAP Message Security 1.1, Username Token Profile 1.1, X.509 Certificate Token Profile 1.1, SAML Token Profile 1.1, Kerberos Token Profile 1.1, Basic Security Profile 1.1

**JAX-WS RI standards supported ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services))**

- JAX-WS 2.0/2.1/2.2 (JSR 224)
- WS-I Basic Profile 1.2 and 2.0
- WS-I Attachments Profile 1.0
- WS-I Simple SOAP Binding Profile 1.0
- WS-Addressing 1.0 - Core, SOAP Binding, WSDL Binding

From above details, we can say SOAP WS doesn't support JAX-WS 2.0/1/2 standards. However i want to know officially from Spring-WS team that whether it is JAX-WS standard compliant?
Please let me know if my question needs to be elaborated in specific view or purpose.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. JAX-WS is an API. Spring-WS is not an implementation of that API. So Spring-WS can't be compliant with JAX-WS.

Comment: @AndreasVeithen thanks for the comments Andreas. The reason why i used word "features" is to avoid saying JAX-WS API. Just wanted to know if Spring-WS does gives all features specified in JAX-WS. Anyhow i got your answer and it should be clear that Spring-WS is independent of JAX-WS in terms of implementation standards.